# Filter Operator predicate function returns all items in the array

Tags: angular, filter, rxjs, observable, ngrx

I have an Observable of an array of objects. Each object has an 'id' property. I'm using the filter method with the goal of only returning an observable of an object that matches a specific id.

When I implement the following code, the predicate function is returning the entire array. My expectation is that only ONE item passes.

```
    this.blog$ = this.store.select('posts', 'blogs').pipe(
      filter((post, index) => {
        console.log(post[index].id == this.id);
        return post[index].id == this.id
      }),
    ).subscribe(x=>console.log(x))
```

[image]

The first console log is inside the filter function, the second called from the subscribe method.

If my comparator function evaluates to truthy, only for a certain id, how can I correctly yield just the passing object?

Comment: The rxjs `filter` function is used to filter each `emit`, so if this emits once with an array, you will need to use the arrays `filter` function along with `map` instead

Comment: Ok that's getting me somewhere. I do see each item now when doing posts.filter(post => post.id = this.id) inside the filter operator. But where is the map function applied? Could you provide this as an answer?

Comment: Are you referring to  the array map method?

Comment: No, to the RXJS map function https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html. I've added an answer below, hope that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rxjs filter function is used to filter each emit, so if this emits once with an array, you will need to use the arrays filter function along with [map](http://earnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html.) instead

```
this.blog$ = this.store.select('posts', 'blogs').pipe(
  map((posts) => posts.filter((post) => post.id == this.id))
).subscribe(x=>console.log(x))
```

Alternately, if you only need the first match, and want the result as an object instead of an array with 1 element, just use the `find` array function instead:

```
this.blog$ = this.store.select('posts', 'blogs').pipe(
  map((posts) => posts.find((post) => post.id == this.id))
).subscribe(x=>console.log(x))
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes the distinction between array.filter and the rxjs operator 'filter' very clear.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, you can use `find` if you'd rather get the item instead of an array. It should also be more efficient, as it breaks the loop as soon as it finds a match

Answer (score 0):

A full rx alternative would be:

```js
this.blog$ = this.store.select('posts', 'blogs').pipe(
  mergeAll(),
  filter(post => post.id == this.id)
).subscribe(post => console.log(post))
```